# Creating empty collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to copy a MongoDB collection from one database to some other database. I need to create an *empty* collection if there was no data in the source collection. How to do that in nodejs using mongoose libraray?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to make it more clear. Please review that edit and feel free to revert/edit further if needed.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux still, this question lacks about everything. voting to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient way of copying a collection from a DB to an other is to use [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)/[mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) from your shell:

```
sh$ echo 'db.createCollection("some_collection")' | mongo my_dst_db 
sh$ mongodump  --db my_src_db --collection some_collection --out=- | \
    mongorestore --db my_dst_db --collection some_collection --dir=-
```

The first command will use `mongo` to create the destination collection. This is required given your use case as, from what I've just tested, `mongorestore` will not create an empty collection. After that, this is just a dump/restore process.

Please note that `mongodump` will accept a [`--query`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--query) parameter in case you need a *partial* copy of your collection.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB being a NoSQL database, doesn't enforce a strict schema structure like traditional SQL database. So u don't need to create a schema.
Lets consider an example where we need to create a student collection having name, age, weight. So if we just write

```
db.createCollection("students")
```

**The above line has created an empty collection already. So we don't need to do anything specific to create an empty collection. This is the flexibility provided by NoSQL databases like MongoDB. Then whenever we want to populate the database. We just write**

```
db.students.insertOne({ "name": "Chris","age": 23, "weight": 67});
```

But if you still want to create a schema you can refer this [collection's schema using validation in mongodb](https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/web-development/mongodb-create-collection).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection.createCollection().
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-createCollection

This is how I create an empty collection.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");

    const mongod = mongoose.connection;

    mongod.once('open', function (){
        mongod.db.createCollection("emptyCollection", function(){
            console.log("done");
        })
    })
```