# create new collection in mongodb by adding index in system.indexes

Tags: mongodb, collections

when I attempt to insert new document manually in system.indexes collection in mongodb,new collection created.here goes the code

```
   {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "code" : 1
    },
    "name" : "code_1",
    "ns" : "mydb.collection"
}
```

where collection is my collection name which is not already present in database and mydb is my database name. Why new collection is getting created?

Comment: This appears to be the third time you've asked this question in the past two days ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124177/creating-empty-collection-in-mongodb) with another account). It's better to edit and improve your existing question instead of asking it multiple times. Anyway, see Salvador's answer about using `createCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create collection by adding index manually in system.indexes.

Why are you asking us this? You already tried to add a new index to system.indexes. Has a new collection been created? If yes, then yes it is possible, if no, then not possible.

> Is this a correct way?

How do you think? Have you read somewhere in documentation that in order to create a new collection you need to dance around and to create manually indexes in some system defined collection? Or may be it [was written in documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) that `db.createCollection(name, options)` is what you should do or if you so desire you can just [insert a document in a non existed collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) and it will create it.

So why after all this one might think that the correct way is to do some manipulation with system.indexes?

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @Salvador Dali's answer strongly discouraging you to do modify `system.index` directly: if for some reason you really don't want/can't use `createCollection`, just remember this is a wrapper around the [create command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/create/).

You can issue yourself such command to create a new collection:

```
db.runCommand( { create: "collection" } )
```

---

As about inserting an entry in `system.indexes`: from the [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/#%3Cdatabase%3E.system.indexes):

> *Deprecated since version 3.0: Access this data using listIndexes.*
>
> The `<database>.system.indexes` collection lists all the indexes in the database.

By reading that it appears that `system.indexes` should be considered as read-only (its direct use is even deprecated since 3.0). The behavior you observed should be considered as *unspecified*. And so *unreliable* and *subject to change without further notices*.

If you really need to understand *why* it behave that way, maybe you should take a look at the source code or ask the question on the MongoDB developer mailing list. There you could have all the insights.